# How is this circumstance with jQuery possible?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to bind certain click handlers etc to a dynamically loaded element.  My hook for adding these handlers is the element's "ready" event.  However, I find when I come to attach the click handlers, the element is undefined.  How is it possible that the following alert shows '0'?

```
<script language="javascript">
  $('#widget').ready(function(){
      alert($('#widget').length);
  });
</script>
```

Edit:

I actually made the circumstance described as simple as possible.  In fact, it's slightly more complicated, as I actually want to attach events to elements contained within #widget.  What I'm really looking for is a reliable way to determine when #widget has finished loading so I can access items within it.

Comment: What kind of element is `#widget`?

Comment: It's a div - just a container for other elements

Comment: @Paul There is no `load` event of a `div`. You can only attach `load` event to `img` or `window`. You may want the generic `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`.

Comment: @Alex - do you mean there's no *ready* event of a div?  I've tried document ready, and see the same problem.

Comment: @Paul Nope, there is no `ready` on a `div`, as far as I know. What kind of things are you waiting for to? Images loaded, or it just being ready to manipulate?

Comment: @Alex, I want to add hover events to child elements, populate child elements with external values etc.  So I need to be certain that #widget is fully loaded before proceeding.

Comment: @Paul In that case, just use `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`.

Comment: Thanks, but like I said, that doesn't work either.  So I suppose I'm back to the beginning - how is this circumstance possible?  Is it possible something else could be interfering?

Comment: @Paul I'd need to see all the code to be able to tell you that.

Comment: We need to know how you are loading information into your page. If you are using the `load()` function (http://api.jquery.com/load/), then using the success callback function would ensure the `#widget` content has loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your input. No, I'm not using Load() either on this element, or its parent. The #widget element is added dynamically to a dynamically-added parent.  The parent is constructed client-side and #widget itself is returned as HTML from a web service request.

Comment: I've managed to do an intermediate workaround using setTimeout, which smells a bit, but seems to have solved the issue - basically if I can wait for a short period, then the DOM appears to settle down and the selectors all work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can call `ready()` on anything besides `document`.

If you want to attach handlers to elements which are not in the DOM yet, use `live()` to bind them or attach an event handler to the consistent parent and examine `which.target` when the event bubbles up (pretty much what `live()` does).

Comment: Thanks, have edited my question to be more clear (hopefully).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at jQuery's [`live` method](http://api.jquery.com/live/). It attaches a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now *and in the future*.

```
$('#widget').live('click', function() {
  alert('#widget clicked');
});
```

So when new elements are added to the document with the ID of `#widget`, they'll get the click handler.